# Using and reading a variable from Knockout.js in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, chart.js

I'm using knockout.js with Jquery to pull pd-Data from an IO and continually update it. My goal is to then cross this with chart.js to graph that pd-data over time. My problem is that my chart is not updating with any of the data.

I currently have the API for pulling the data in a separate .js file, but the chart.js is under a `<script>` tag in the html file. I have tried a few different methods, such as tagging the  with an id and using document.getElementById(). So far no luck.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  pdData = parseInt(document.getElementById("value").value);
  addData(window.myLine, time, pdData);
  removeData(window.myLine);
}, 3000);

function addData(chart, label, data) {
  config.data.labels.push(label);
  config.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
    dataset.data.push(data);
  });
  window.myLine.update();
}

function removeData(chart) {
  config.data.labels.pop();
  config.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
    dataset.data.pop();
  });
  window.myLine.update();
}
```

I can add more from the API script if needed, but my current issue is just that pdData is not loading with a value (or any value) and the chart is not updating with increasing times and updated data. My only error I receive is that `.update()` is not a valid function for the chart I created.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is create a custom binding handler for ChartJS:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.chartJS = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        // do the chartJS stuff here
        // access the chart data by calling valueAccessor()
    }
};
```

Then you would call it in your template like so:

```
<canvas data-bind="chartJS: myChartData"></canvas>
```

Where `myChartData` would be an (observable) property on your viewmodel. Should the data change (through an AJAX call), your chart will update automatically.